# Probability question that involves atleast

Tags: probability

> In a class 18 of the 28 students in a class bought sushi for their lunch.
>   Suppose 12 students from that class are randomly selected. 
>   Calculate the probability that at least 11 of the 12 students selected bought sushi for their 
>   lunch that week.

Can someone please explain to me how to solve these types of questions. Thank you

Comment: You know that "at least $11$" means, in this case, $!!$ or $12$.. Find the probability that exactly $11$ brought sushi, that exactly $12$ did, and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the count of the 12 students selected who eat sushi.

$\begin{align}\Pr(S\geq 11) & = \Pr(S=11 \cup S=12) \\ & = \Pr(S=11)+\Pr(S=12) \\ & = \frac{{^{18}C_{11}}{^{10}C_1}+{^{18}C_{12}}}{^{28}C_{12}}\end{align}$

This is the probability of selecting either 11 of 18 sushi( and 1 of the 10 others), or 12 of 18 sushi, out of all the ways to select 12 of 28 students.

**Remark:** "at least" means "greater than or equal to".  In problems where you can calculate the probabilities of "exactly", this means summing the individual probabilities.

Sometimes it may be easier to find the complement (though not in this example).  Remember that: $\Pr($at least something$) = 1 - P($less than something$)$.

Answer (score 2):

As Andre commented, "at least 11" means, in this case, 11 or 12. So, find the the numbers for 11 and 12, and then add them. Answer${}=\dfrac{^{18}C_{12}+{^{18}C_{11}}\cdot10}{^{28}C_{12}}$

Comment: Use `{18\choose 12}` and marvel.

Comment: Very quick and compact. I would suggest that in order to help OP understand similar probability calculations, some additional explanation be given.

Comment: Edits are not allowed after a while. bad luck.

Comment: a+^{18}C_{11} looks oddly bad: the "18" looks like a right superscript on the "+" rather than like a left superscript on the "C".  I changed it to a+{^18}C_{11} and that did it.  Compare: $a+^{18}C_{11}$ versus $a+{^{18}C_{11}}$. ${}\qquad{}$